# Duplicate key issue with inheritance(equals () )

Tags: java, inheritance

```
@Data
public class Product {

    protected String name;
    protected String systemId;
    protected String productId;
    protected String productPartId;
    protected Pricing pricing;
    protected String productUid;
    protected String productPartUid;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return Objects.equals(systemId, product.systemId) && Objects.equals(productId, product.productId) &&
                Objects.equals(productPartId, product.productPartId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(systemId, productId, productPartId);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RelatedProduct extends Product {

    private boolean isMandatory;
}
```

Note: I am partially aware of the dangers of overriding equals() in subclass but it will never be the case for me. The {systemId, productId, productPartId} in the base class will always be the key for both base and extended classes. In other words, even if two RelatedProduct instances are to be compared, I want **the base class equals() method to be used.**

I tried both the approaches in vain, seems I have made some fundamental mistake.

Approach-1(Desirable):
Place both classes in different packages with the Product class fields as private.

Approach-2(Compromise):
Place both classes in same packages with the Product class fields as protected.

Code giving error for a field that belongs only to the subclass and is NOT part of the base class equals() :

```
List<Product> customerProducts = ...;
List<RelatedProduct>relatedProducts = ...;

Map<RelatedProduct, RelatedProduct> conceptRelatedProductsMap = relatedProducts.stream().
                       collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),Function.identity()));

 customerProducts.forEach(customerProduct -> {

                    Optional<RelatedProduct> conceptProduct = Optional.ofNullable
                            (conceptRelatedProductsMap.get(customerProduct));

                    if (conceptProduct.isPresent()) {
                        //Do something
                    }

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key RelatedProduct(isMandatory=false) (attempted merging values RelatedProduct(isMandatory=false) and RelatedProduct(isMandatory=false))
```

Using Approach-2, I tried the below.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RelatedProduct extends Product {

    private boolean isMandatory;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        return super.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

It got past the duplicate key issue block but it fails to behave expectedly where the subclass object and parent class object are being compared:

```
conceptRelatedProductsMap.get(customerProduct) //Returns null.
```

Comment: I think your issue is the fact that you are using the /@Data annotation. Lombok is going to generate equals and hashcode methods if you use the /@Data annotation.  Delete the /@Data annotation.  Use the Lombok /@Getter /@Setter annotations as it looks like you want to use those convenient annotations instead of defining getter and setter methods.

Comment: @M.Rizzo I tried it but the same results. I think I am getting something fundamentally wrong with inheritance + equals(). I have edited my post to include more details.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error occurs when collecting with [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) method, correct? It seems then you are having duplicate entries (according to their `equals` and `hashCode` implementations) inside the `relatedProducts` list. Then you need to decide what to do for duplicate keys (for example by using corresponding `toMap` overload method).